# Populate dialog from data grid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid

**Solution**

In order to set this thread as resolved, let me write down what i changed in order to have my code working:

- Changed bean to @ViewScoped;
- Alter the id of Update="" for the id of the dialog form;
- After looking for the error (Cannot find component with expression.." i've re-checked the generated HTML to confirm the id and it was much longer since ther are automatically generated. After replacing the id with the automatic one, everything was ok.

Thanks to @Jaqen H'ghar for the help :)

---

I have this panel to update a given table columns, and I want to do this using a dialog box, populated with each column data.

**This is my page:**

```
<h:form prependId="true" id="tableForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="gridLabel, gridEntry">
        <h:outputText value="Table Name: " />
        <h:inputText value="#{updObj.title}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:dataTable var="column"
        value="#{tableBean.getTableColumns(updObj)}"
        id="columnsTable">

        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.title}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Type">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.type}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Size">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.size}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Not null">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{column.notNull}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Primary key">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{column.primaryKey}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Edit column">
            <p:commandButton value="Edit column"
                actionListener="#{tableBean.personalmethod(column)}"
                update="updateColumnDialog:updateColumnGrid" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                title="Edit this column"
                oncomplete="PF('updateColumnDialog').show();" />

        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>


    <p:dialog id="updateColumnDialog" widgetVar="updateColumnDialog"
        header="Edit Column" height="200">

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="updateColumnGrid">

            <h:outputText value="Column name: " />
            <h:inputText id="updateColName"
                value="#{tableBean.updatedColumnName}" />
            <h:outputText value="Column type: " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="updateSelectColumnTypes"
                value="#{tableBean.selectedColumnType}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{tableBean.columnTypes}"
                    var="columnType" itemLabel="#{columnType}"
                    itemValue="#{columnType}" id="updateSelectColumnType" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputText value="Size: " />
            <p:spinner id="updateSize"
                value="#{tableBean.updatedColumnSize}" />

            <h:outputText value="Not null: " />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="updateNotNull"
                value="#{tableBean.updatedColumnNotNull}" />

            <h:outputText value="Primary Key: " />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="updatePrimaryKey"
                value="#{tableBean.updatedColumnPrimaryKey}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

**TableBean:**

```
private String updatedColumnName = "";
private String updatedColumnType = "";
private double updatedColumnSize = 0.0;
private boolean updatedColumnNotNull = false;
private boolean updatedColumnPrimaryKey = false;
private List<String> columnTypes =  new ArrayList<String>();

public void personalmethod(ColumnDTO updateColumn) {
    this.setUpdatedColumnName(updateColumn.getTitle());
    this.setUpdatedColumnType(updateColumn.getType());
    this.setUpdatedColumnSize(updateColumn.getSize());
    this.setUpdatedColumnNotNull(updateColumn.isNotNull());
    this.setUpdatedColumnPrimaryKey(updateColumn.isPrimaryKey());
}

 public List<ColumnDto> getTableColumns(TableDTO contextTable) {
    List<ColumnDto> contextTableColumns = new ArrayList<ColumnDto>();

    for (ColumnDto myColumnDto: contextTable.getColumns().values()) {
        contextTableColumns.add(myColumnDto);
    }

    return contextTableColumns;
}
```

From what I tried: put ID on the datagrid on the dialog, namings like `<form:datagrid>` and `@RequestScoped` but I can only have the dialog poping up, but with the form all blank.

Can you help me figuring out what's missing?

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: Is it requestscoped? I'd say it should be viewscoped. If it is already try to put the dialog below the main form, and put a form inside the dialog itself (and update the references to it)

Comment: Hi there @JaqenH'ghar, thanks for your fast replay.

I've set the Bean as ViewScoped and put a form inside the dialog. I've also extracted the dialog from the main form as you told.

However, the dialog keeps being called, but the values of the bean are not being displayed. 

I'll now give a shot from giaffa86 alternative and i'll let you know for improvements.

Comment: I've set the dialog with the form, but i've also updated the reference:  `update="updateColumnDialog:updateColumnGrid"` but i have an "Cannot find component with expression" error. This isn't the correct way to call the component?

Comment: It is outside the main form now? Then I think you need ":updateColumnDialog:updateColumnGrid" (note the first colon). If you put a form inside it probably ":updateColumnDialog:formId"

Comment: Yes, it is outside of the main form.

I have this (Synthesized):
`update=":updateColumnDialogId:columnUpdateDialogForm"
...
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="updateColumnDialogId" widgetVar="updateColumnDialog" >
<h:form id="columnUpdateDialogForm">....
</h:form>
</p:dialog>`

But i have now:  Cannot find component with expression ":updateColumnDialogId:columnUpdateDialogForm" 

Thanks for your attention and patience! :)

Comment: Sorry should be just update=":columnUpdateDialogForm"

Comment: Sorry @JaqenH'ghar, but i still have `Cannot find component with expression ":columnUpdateDialogForm"` 

However, i have the prependId="true" in my first form. Maybe the second has to have this tag as well...?

Comment: You can view the resulting html and search for "columnUpdateDialogForm", then you can see what the id actually is

Comment: Hi again @JaqenH'ghar!

So, since the ids of the view were being generated automatically, of course the update tag could not find the dialog.

I've set the automatic generated id, and the dialog is populated correctly! :).

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should set a property when h:commandButton is fired as explained in [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-setpropertyactionlistener-example/) and the pass it to dialog.

As mentioned by [Jaqen H'ghar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448565/populate-dialog-from-data-grid#comment43354804_27448565), me either would switch to `@ViewScoped` and would use two different form and put the second one inside dialog.